# Need help! making my Arduino code work

Tags: c, arduino

I'm having some trouble with my arduino code and I need help making it work, it is going to be used to control some LED lights. Brighten, darken, blink, and make them run.

I have added comments all over the script so you can read the problems and so on.

```
/*This script is supposed to make a arduino board control the lights on a lego creation for a school project.
  Button1 should make lights brighter
  Button2 should make ligts shine less
  Button3 should make the light blink
  Button4 is supposed to make the light run after each other.
*/

//Setting up all the lights and buttons
const int lights[] = {9, 8, 7};
int light = 0;

const int button1 = 24;
int buttonstate1 = 0;
const int button2 = 25;
int buttonstate2 = 0;
const int button3 = 26;
int buttonstate3 = 0;
const int button4 = 27;
int buttonstate4 = 0;
int lightStrength = 50;
int blinkToggle = 0;

//Setting up the input's and output's
void setup() {
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);
  pinMode(button4, INPUT);
  pinMode(lights[0], OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lights[1], OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lights[2], OUTPUT);

  //Here i have a problem with make the list take all in one line of code.
  analogWrite(lights[0], lightStrength);
  analogWrite(lights[1], lightStrength);
  analogWrite(lights[2], lightStrength);

}

void loop() {
//checking if the buttons are being pressed
buttonstate1 = digitalRead(button1);
buttonstate2 = digitalRead(button2);
buttonstate3 = digitalRead(button3);
buttonstate1 = digitalRead(button4);

//Make the lights brighter
  while (lightStrength <= 235){
    if (buttonstate1 == HIGH){
      delay(10);
      lightStrength = lightStrength + 1;
      delay(10);
      analogWrite(lights[0], lightStrength);
      analogWrite(lights[1], lightStrength);
      analogWrite(lights[2], lightStrength);
     }
   }

//make the lights darker
  while (lightStrength >= 45){
    if (buttonstate2 == HIGH){
      delay(5);
      lightStrength = lightStrength - 1;
      delay(5);
      analogWrite(lights[0], lightStrength);
      analogWrite(lights[1], lightStrength);
      analogWrite(lights[2], lightStrength);
    }
  }

//Blink the lights
  while(blinkToggle == 1){
    if (buttonstate3 == HIGH){
      delay(100);
      blinkToggle = 0;
    }
  }
  while(blinkToggle == 0){
    if (buttonstate3 == HIGH){
      delay(100);
      blinkToggle = 1;
    }
  }
  while(blinkToggle == 1){
    delay(150);
    analogWrite(lights[0], 0);
    analogWrite(lights[1], 0);
    analogWrite(lights[2], 0);
    delay(150);
    analogWrite(lights[0], lightStrength);
    analogWrite(lights[1], lightStrength);
    analogWrite(lights[2], lightStrength);
  }

//make the lights run (Not completed because the other code didn't work)
  if (buttonstate4 == HIGH){
    delay(100);

  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: LED's are current controlled, not voltage controlled, are you sure the hardware is correct? And what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, asking "need help" is kind of general.. You should definitely ask a better question. For instance I could not understand fully what you meant, what the problems are and what is the expected behavior in some cases (for instance, what happens if I press more buttons?).

Anyway this is not a comment but an answer, because there are a few general mistakes in your code, and maybe these are enough to make your code worl.

for instance, you wrote all your tests as

```
while (lightStrength <= 235){
    if (buttonstate1 == HIGH){
```

Well, if your button is low then `lightStrength` will not be incremented, the loop will never reach its ending and so the program will be stuck in there. I suggest you to change your code into

```
if (buttonstate1 == HIGH){
    while (lightStrength <= 235){
```

This will not halt your code.

Then the tests for `blinkToggle` are wrong. You should not test them in a while, but with an if (e.g. `if(blinkToggle == 1){`).

The button 4 is not implemented, and I don't understand what is its behavior, so I cannot tell you how to implement it.

I did not understand the `//Here i have a problem with make the list take all in one line of code.` comment. If you want to write the same value without repeating it use a for loop:

```
byte i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    analogWrite(lights[i], lightStrength);
```

And now, some advices for your program.

First of all, debouncing. If you don't know what bouncing is, look [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) or search on google. Anyway I found that the Bounce2 library is very useful whenever you have to deal with buttons. Search for its examples or simply ask to see some more examples.

And.. I suggest you to change your approach in this program. A FSM (Finite State Machine) approach is more suitable for this. Even without using complicated libraries, just plain C, you can make a very solid program